# Downloading a file from server to client's computer

Tags: php, performance, security, download

I have a folder in my  root dir called `files`.
This folder contains files ranging from `1 Kb-1 GB`.

I want a php script that can simply download a file asynchronously using AJAX.

This codes initiates download scripts when a file is clicked:

**JQUERY**

```
$('.download').click(function(){
   var src =$(this).attr('src');  
   $.post('download.php',{
      src :  src //contains name of file 
    },function(data){
      alert('Downloaded!');
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
   $path = 'files/'.$_POST['src'];
   //here the download script must go!
?>
```

Which would be the **best, fastest and secure** way to download a file?

Comment: "I want a php script that can simply download a file asynchronously using AJAX." — Why? What do you need to do that can't be done by just letting the server manage it? Why do you need to involve Ajax?

Answer (score 4):

```php
<?php
/**
 * download.php
 */

if (!empty($_GET['file'])) {
    // Security, down allow to pass ANY PATH in your server
    $fileName = basename($_GET['file']);
} else {
    return;
}

$filePath = '???/files/' . $fileName;
if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
    return;
}

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile($filePath);
```

And actually AJAX request is unnecessary, when using `Content-disposition: attachment`:

```
<a href="download.php?file=file1.pdf">File1</a>
```

Comment: what if i dont know the `content-type` ?

Comment: Just dont use it when. It helps browser to determine program for file opening (movie, image, MS word etc.)

Comment: You can't not use a Content-Type. PHP will default to claiming it is an HTML document unless you override that.

Comment: Upvote.... Don't want to be a nit-picker but you have a typo for 'file_exits'. It should be 'file_exists'. Some people might not know how to correct this error, so please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

To continue on the original answer, I've added a few php functions to make it a bit more programmatic:

```
$filePath = $_GET['path'];
$fileName = basename($filePath);
if (empty($filePath)) {
    echo "'path' cannot be empty";
    exit;
}

if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
    echo "'$filePath' does not exist";
    exit;
}

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);
header("Content-type: " . mime_content_type($filePath));
readfile($filePath);
```

If your sever requires strong security, do not use this function without pre-validating the user in the same script. Or use the security measures posted by the original answer. This script will allow any file on your server to be downloaded by a user.